# Why does lodash union shuffle my objects?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How does union work?
Why it union my array in random order?

Is there a way I can union in excatly same my `result` order?

[image: result]
[image: ids]

```
result = {
-KvpYbfRfqMXLOsGH7fh : "-KvpYbfRfqMXLOsGH7fh",
-KvpYcMTcRQk5KYawqdR : "-KvpYcMTcRQk5KYawqdR",
-KvpYcjvkVfdC9a4Q9FO : "-KvpYcjvkVfdC9a4Q9FO",
-KvpYd9-1mbm016eV4MZ : "-KvpYd9-1mbm016eV4MZ",
-KvpYduO7YXkW1DoEQak : "-KvpYduO7YXkW1DoEQak",
-KvpYeMtsePxGrvdoBEd : "-KvpYeMtsePxGrvdoBEd",
-KvpYfPluPG5q4e_D35w : "-KvpYfPluPG5q4e_D35w",
-KvpYgGSQsrpR0g_084h : "-KvpYgGSQsrpR0g_084h",
-KvpYgpOGrwjnxy9F7SF : "-KvpYgpOGrwjnxy9F7SF",
-KvpYhU_NXWYIfC2H-UM : "-KvpYhU_NXWYIfC2H-UM",
}
   const result = Object.keys(action.response.result)
    return { 
      ...state,
      ids: _.union(result, state.ids),
    }
```

Comment: It uses a `Set` so the order is not preserved.

Comment: Please provide code and data with which the problem can be reproduced. Images are of little use.

Comment: According to documentation it uses SameValueZero (http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero). Since those are strings it comes down to SameValueNonNumber (http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluenonnumber). "If x and y are exactly the same sequence of code units (same length and same code units at corresponding indices), return true; otherwise, return false." So there is no alphabetic order.

Comment: @trincot done....

Comment: What is expected result? Is requirement to create an object where property names are in a specific order?

Comment: @guest271314 . I edited my question. Expected result is return union which same order as my `result` object

Comment: JavaScript plain object property names are not ordered. You can use a `Map` or create an `Array` of objects if the objects should be ordered in a specific order.

Comment: @Walk Thank you for explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript plain object property names are not stored in a specific order.

You can use `Map`, `Set` or `Array` to store objects in a specific order

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
let map = new Map();
arr.forEach(value => map.set(value, {[value]:value}));

let b = map.get("b");

let res = [...map.values()];

JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(res.find(prop => Object.keys(prop).pop() === "b"));

JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(res[1]);
```

Comment: I got the expected result with this `Object.keys(o).sort()` Is that ok to use this?

Comment: If an array is sufficient, yes.